# Do I need to know Typescript to learn Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some time ago I decided to learn Angular. I didn't know JavaScript any well, so I spent several months to learn it (I am not an expert or anything, but I am able to create some simple applications now). Now that I thought I am ready to Angular (the 2nd version of which became available), I opened the official website (https://angular.io/) and was stunned to see that their docs suggest that I need to know Typescript as well to write some code now. JS version of the docs is not yet ready and suggests you to go to the Typescript docs instead.

Is Angular 2 available for the Javascript only? If so, are there any official docs on it?

Comment: This is not the type of questions expected here. Usually there is some code related to the question. In terms of Angular, under the 5min quickstart there is a blue box that literally says "Although we're getting started in TypeScript, you can also write Angular 2 apps in Dart and JavaScript. Just select either of those languages from the combo-box in the banner."

Comment: @ODelibalta, yeah, but the Tutorial, Developer guides, and the Basics sections send you to the Typescript version, saying that it is not available for pure JS. I wonder how one can learn it, if there are no official docs for it.

Comment: TypeScript is a Superset of JavaScript;  if you know how to write JavaScript, you are 80% of the way to writing TypeScript;  TypeScript can read JavaScript code and output it without changes, or interpret TypeScript and generate the corresponding JavaScript.  In general, the enhancements in TypeScript are related to type safety, and are very easy for most developers to comprehend.  However, if you must know the JavaScript equivalent, you can examine the compiled output created by the samples.

Comment: Yes, Angular 2 is available for pure JS. And yes, you probably need to know TS, because most of learning materials that you will find are meant for TS, and Angular 2 was designed to offer the best experience for TS developers (JS devs that do ES.next+Babel feel fine, too). Even if you write ES5 in Angular 2, you need to know how the things are done in TS and how they are translated to ES5.

Comment: @Deka87 [Here is the link](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) there is a drop down where it says "5 min quickstart" and one of the options is "Angular 2 for JavaScript" ... I want to ask you if you are serious with your reply but I find myself not be able to even pretend to care at this point. Good luck to you

Comment: @ODelibalta, yeah, sorry I was more confused about the docs available and should have thought over the question much better. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you learn Angular 2 and not the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. TypeScript is not required to use Angular 2. It's not even the default. That said, TypeScript would benefit you to learn if your job was exclusively calling for front-end development specifically with Angular 2.0.

Even the official [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) article starts off with plain ol' JavaScript.

All of their code samples and tutorials will *eventually* be available in JavaScript. Their wording simply says it's "not yet available in JavaScript".

Comment: If you're dependent on tutorials to learn the API, you're probably going to have to search around or wait for more resources to come available. If, however, you can figure out how to use features by simply reading the docs, you're good to go.

Comment: Developer guide is also unavailable for JS, nor the Basics.

Comment: Sure, but you asked if it's necessary to know TypeScript to learn Angular. It's not, but you need the power of inference or a willingness to wait for their team to finish documentation.

Comment: So Typescript seems to be default for Angular 2, however not the only one. There are also no docs for pure JS at the moment. That answers my questions.

Comment: It's *not* the default, but it is suggested. It's just the first pass for their docs given that it is their suggested way of using the framework.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. One last question. If you use Angualar 2, do you use it with Typescript or pure JS?

Comment: I don't use TypeScript. Not a fan.